# Equivalent to R findInterval() function in SAS IML

Tags: r, sas

Is there anything similar to R's `findInterval` (or `cut`) in SAS, specifically in IML?

I'm converting an R program of mine that does Monte Carlo simulations to IML, and it uses `findInterval` to convert the numbers from the random number generator to an output state. I can write something in IML to replace it, but it's terribly slow compared to the original. This is because `findInterval` takes advantage of compiled C code; is there anything similar that I can use in SAS?

Comment: I should probably describe what it is that `findInterval` does! Given a value x and a vector of sorted cutpoints vec, it finds those cutpoints that x lies between, ie which interval x falls into. More precisely, if `vec[i] < x < vec[i+1]`, then `findInterval` returns `i`. The argument `x` can also be a vector, in which case it returns a vector of intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your breaks uniform (equal probability) or not?
For uniform breaks, you can use ceil(k*u) where u is the vector or random uniform numbers.
For example, if you want 10 observations randomly assigned to the numbers 1-4 with equal probability, you can say

```
y = ceil(4*ranuni(j(10,1)));
```

or, if you want to use the newer random number generator,

```
u = j(10,1); /** allocate **/
call randgen(u, "uniform"); /** fill with U[0,1] **/
y = ceil(4*u);
```

For unequal probability, use the "table" distribution. For example,

```
p = {0.1 0.5 0.2 0.2}; /** four categories with given probabilities **/
y = j(10, 1); 
call randgen(y, "Table", p); /** fills with 1-4 with probability p **/
```

You might be interested in using the SampleWithReplace module from Chapter 13 of my book, *Statistical Programming with SAS/IML software*.  You can download the code and see an example of its use at 
http://blogs.sas.com/iml/index.php?/archives/75-Hey!-Those-Two-People-Have-the-Same-Initials!.html

Both of these techniques eliminate the need for findInterval because they produce the categories directly. If you REALLY REALLY think you need to bin the random numbers, you can use the algorithm I describe here:
http://blogs.sas.com/iml/index.php?/archives/80-Count-the-Number-of-Points-in-Bins-Efficiently.html

Comment: By the way, SAS 9.3 introduced the BIN function into the SAS/IML language. See http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/07/15/cut-pts-and-uneven-bins/